# ¿Cómo hago para que el formulario envíe el action a la misma página en php?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Resulta que tengo este formulario:

```html
  <form action="index.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form">
          <h3 class="row justify-content-center mt-5">Seleccione el tiempo en minutos que estará su imagen en línea</h3>
          <div class="row justify-content-center mt-1">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">1</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">5</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">15</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">30</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">60</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
            <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" class="input-file">
            <label for="imagen" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-black js-labelFile">
              <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>
              <span class="js-fileName">Elija la imagen a subir</span>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-red" value="Subir Imagen">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

afortunadamente el formulario está bién funcional, esto envía datos mediante una petición post al archivo data.php que es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Imagen</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="timer()" oncontextmenu="return false" ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false" onkeydown="return false">
    <?php
    // Informacion de la imagen
      $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
      $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
      $tamano = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];

      //Crea la carpeta imagenes
      $carpetaImagenes = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'imagenes-momentaneas/imagenes';
      if (!is_dir($carpetaImagenes)) {
          mkdir($carpetaImagenes, 0775);
      }
      if (!is_writable($carpetaImagenes)) {
          chmod($carpetaImagenes, 0775);
      }

      //Crea la carpeta Uploads
      $carpetaUploads = $carpetaImagenes.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads';
      if (!is_dir($carpetaUploads)) {
          mkdir($carpetaUploads, 0775);
      }
      if (!is_writable($carpetaUploads)) {
          chmod($carpetaUploads, 0775);
      }
      if ($_FILES['imagen']['size'] != 0 && $_FILES['imagen']['type'] === 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['imagen']['type'] === 'image/jpg' || $_FILES['imagen']['type'] === 'image/png' || $_FILES['imagen']['type'] === 'image/gif')
      {
        // Envia la imagen del directorio temporar al servidor
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $carpetaUploads.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$nombre);
        }else {

      }
      // Path de donde va a estar la imagen ya subida
      $path = $carpetaUploads.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$nombre;
      //Muestra la imagen en base 64
      echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($path))."' />";


    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

que es el que se encarga de subir la imagen y mostrarla, pero yo quiero que la imagen se muestre en el archivo principal index.php ¿Cómo hago esto? Porque cuando coloco el código de data.php en el index.php me sale este error:

[image: Errores]

Ya que la imagen no está subida como es lógico, así que yo quiero que ese código aparezca cuando la imagen se suba, para que la pueda mostrar ahí mismo en el index, más bien lo que quiero es que la imagen se suba, y en el index se muestre la url para que el usuario la pueda copiar y enviársela a otra persona para que pueda ver la iamgen. Además, quiero generar un nombre nuevo aleatorio, para así cuando otro usuario suba una imagen con el mismo nombre esta no se sobreescriba, vi [en un foro](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/cambiar-nombre-archivo-que-subo-servidor-999565/) que se puede usar [la función rand](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php), pero noto que solo es para generar números aleatorios, y yo quiero generar nombres aleatorios, así que si alguien me puede dar un norte para esto lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**

engloba el código que procesa el file en un if/else que chequea si hay un file subido

```
if (!isset($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']) || 
    !file_exists($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']) || 
    !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    echo 'No upload'; // aquí código que aparece cuando no se ha subido nada (puede ir vacio)
}
else
{
// Aquí código que procesa el file upload
}
```

sacado/adaptado de:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492283/1423096

**2** para agregar un número aleatorio al nombre modifica la linea donde se especifica el nombre:

```
 $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
```

lo cambias por

```
 $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
 $extension = pathinfo($nombre, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $nombre = rand().'.'.$extension;
```

si te salta un warning de que pathinfo está deshabilitado usas la alternativa:

```
 $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
 $tmpext=explode(".", $nombre);$extension = end($tmpext);
 $nombre = rand().'.'.$extension;
```

ten en cuenta que rand() por si solo puede llegar a generar muchas colisiones (muchos archivos con el mismo nombre se vana air sobreescribiendo) para evitar esto puedes usar un hash que combine el nombre original con el rand

```
 $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
 $tmpext=explode(".", $nombre);$extension = end($tmpext);
 $nombre = md5($nombre.rand()).'.'.$extension;
```

de esa manera tendras menos posibilidades de que el archivo se sobreescriba